# How to add foreign languages to wine under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wine, fonts, language-support

I want to use "mp3tag.exe" for editing my music files that contains titles in latin (a,b,c,d,...) and greek characters (α,β,ζ,δ,...)
Installing wine under Ubuntu 18.04 worked fine
Installing mp3tag and running under wine worked fine as well (with german & english characters)
BUT
the greek characters don't show up only empty rectangles

I think I have to add the greek language pack to the wine version, but I found no description and no hint how to configure wine to solve this problem.

Comment: Why  use emulated software when you have native solutions that do the same or better? -> Easytag

Comment: Because I found no way in EasyTag or other Linux based tag programs to add CD covers simply by paste & copy

Answer (score -1):

I found something online, I think will be of help to you.

In order to solve the issue, go to:

`Applications -> System Tools -> System Settings` and under the tab "Personal" choose "Language Support". Then change the -keyboard input method system- from IBUS to none.

It would be nice to restart your Ubuntu box.

**NB**: Take a look at the distro before the restart in case it seems not to work, please.

You could visit [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2237582) for more if need be.

Regards!